# prediction accuracy LSTM for time series

Tags: lstm, prediction

This is regarding the accuracy of LSTM network. I am also facing the same issue as [Regression Problem: How to solve the problem of highly decimal input features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55743481/regression-problem-how-to-solve-the-problem-of-highly-decimal-input-features)

The prediction accuracy of up to 4 decimal places is my requirement, but getting only up to 2 decimal places.

I have tried with different loss functions, such as MSE, MAE, HUBER, log Cosh.. but the problem is not yet solved

The code for the model is

```
model=Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(128,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(Seq_length,1)))
 model.add(Dropout(0.2))
 model.add(LSTM(128,return_sequences=True))
 model.add(Dropout(0.2))
 model.add(LSTM(128))
 model.add(Dropout(0.2))
 model.add(Dense(1))
 model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',optimizer='adam')
 model.summary()
```

The predicted value and expected values are typically looks like
Real value = 0.0034561 | Predicted value = 0.0041059

Comment: Welcome! This question needs more detail. How are you pulling the prediction accuracy? A code sample would be helpful to someone trying to answer this question.

Comment: i have edited the question with the sample code...please review